# Error while running analyze table compute statistics in Hive table via EMR (hive 2.0)

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr

Not sure what is the problem here but just a simple analyze table compute statistics is throwing the below error. I tried msck repair and I feel the partition is corrupted. Anything can be done without dropping the partitions?

```
[Code: 500051 , SQL State: HY000]  [Amazon][HiveJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. 
Error Code: 40000 , SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS
,infoMessages:[*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while compiling statement: 
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: 
InvalidObjectException(message:Unsupported expression '__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__' (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400;
Error Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID: ...)):28:27
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your table is partitioned. Please check using `show partitions [db_name.]tablename`.

For non-partitioned table you should use -

```
ANALYZE TABLE [db_name.]tablename COMPUTE STATISTICS
```

For partitioned table you should use -

```
ANALYZE TABLE [db_name.]tablename [PARTITION(partcol1[=val1], partcol2[=val2], ...)]   COMPUTE STATISTICS
```

Answer (score 0):

By which field and type the table is partitioned?

I guess it is not string type. Then `HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION` is a wrong value. Such partition created when you are loading `NULL`s or incompatible data type into partition. Remove that partition location and run `msck repair` again